# SQL SUM only when each value within a group is greater than 0

Tags: sql, group-by, vertica, vsql

Here is a sample data set:

```
ID   Value
1   421
1   532
1   642
2   3413
2   0
2   5323
```

I want a query that, in this case, only sums ID=1 because all of its values are greater than 0. I cannot use a `WHERE` statement that says `WHERE Value > 0` because then ID=2 would still return a value. I feel like this may be an instance where I could possibly use a `OVER(PARTITION BY...)` statement, but I am not familiar enough to use it creatively.

As an aside, I don't simply add a `WHERE ID = 1` statement because this needs to cover a much larger data set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `having`:

```
select id, sum(value)
from t
group by id
having min(value) > 0;
```